# 400 Bad request with axios POST to /api/signin using Passport.JS and Next.JS

Tags: axios, next.js, passport-local, http-status-code-400

I am following the [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-passport-and-next-connect) repo Next.js provides to implement Passport.JS & next connect.

I have a Form Submit Handler which sends the **email** and **password** after validation.

I am using axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function loginSubmit(
  email,
  password,
) {
  const loginData = {
    email,
    password,
  };
  axios
    .post(`/api/signin`, {
      params: loginData,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },

    })
    .then(response => {
    
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response) {
        console.log("error.response ", error.response);
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.log("error.request ", error.request);
      } else if (error.message) {
        // do something other than the other two
      }
}
```

I've done research and a `400 Bad request` means the error is on the client.

Some ideas were to check the URL, flush your DNS in terminal, clear cookies. But none of that worked.

This is the error which get returns:

```
error.response : {
    "data": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Bad Request",
    "headers": {
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-length": "11",
        "date": "Sat, 16 Oct 2021 18:49:44 GMT",
        "keep-alive": "timeout=5"
    },
    "config": {
        "url": "/api/signin",
        "method": "post",
        "data": "{\"params\":{\"email\":\"xxxxxx@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"Aug8162016!\"},\"withCredentials\":true,\"headers\":{\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\"},\"credentials\":\"same-origin\"}",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        }
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

My gut is telling me it's something here.

Any ideas how I can get a more substantial error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you generated POST request body in wrong way.
Try

```js
const data = {
    email,
    password,
  };

  axios
    .post(`/api/signin`, // url
      data, // request body
      { // options
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
```

if it didn't work, you can try sending already stringified body:

```js
const data = {
    email,
    password,
  };

  axios
    .post(`/api/signin`, // url
      JSON.stringify(data), // request body as string
      { // options
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
```

it should work

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work, still getting the same `400 (Bad Request)` error...

Comment: i've updated code, at least one of variants should work

Comment: Actually that worked! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

`axios.post` accepts 3 parameters

1- the url

2- the body

3- options

```
axios
    .post(`/api/signin`, 
      data, 
      {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },

    })
```